# Optimal policy of a Markov Decision Process

Tags: markov-process

I'm not sure about the definition of optimal policy which is usually denoted by $\pi^*$. I'm not sure how we'd usually express optimal policy by, is it the best set of actions that gives the maximum reward?

Answer (score 1):

The policy is usually in the form: $$\pi(a|s) = \text{probability of taking action $a$ in state $s$}$$

Then $\pi^*$ is the policy which will, when starting the game/environment from state $s_0 \sim \rho$, give the highest expected reward.

$$\pi^* = \text{argmax}_{\pi} E_{s_0 \sim \rho} \left[ J(\pi,s_0) \right]$$

Where $J$ is the expected reward of using policy $\pi$, starting on state $s_0$

It's useful for $\pi$ to be stochastic in many cases, which is why it's not simply a set of actions. We also can't talk directly about maximum reward, because the reward you receive is also stochastic, which is why we need to use expected reward instead.